# Android - On every new Android Studio update I need to re-install Fabric Plugin - why

Tags: android, android-studio, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Its about [Fabric plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8002?pr=), whenever I update my android studio I need to re-install the Fabric Plug-in again. Even though I import my old settings after updating the android studio.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to export your settings from the old Android Studio to the new one. It seems plug-ins aren't included in the settings. It only works when you install a patch